# SAML Replay Detection

Tags: refresh, saml, replay

We have a Java based web application which uses SAML 2.0 for SSO. As part of the SSO we have also implemented Single Logout. Can anyone please share info on how to fix the below issue

- User logs into IDP(app1)
- User clicks on the link to the SP(app2)
- User logs out of IDP. A logout request is received by SP and the session is invalidated
- User refreshes the browser that has SP(app2) open and the the original IDP request is resubmitted. The SP processes this request as if it came from the IDP. With this the user is still able to navigate/use app2 even though he has logged out of the IDP.

I think the best solution is to go back to IDP and check if the session(based on SAML SessionIndex is valid) but not sure on how we can do it. Note the browser refresh only works within the window specified NotBefore and NotOnOrAfter. If the user tries to refresh out of this window we have logic that rejects the request/response.

Answer (score 0):

The SP should also check for SAML assertion replay.
Every SAML assertion includes a unique ID.
Your SP should keep track of these until they expire (ie until NotOnOrAfter). When you receive a SAML assertion, if the ID has already been seen by your SP, the SAML assertion should be rejected.

Comment: On similar lines I was thinking about using SessionIndex which is part of the Assertion. Is this unique too?

Comment: Yes, although SessionIndex is optional and often is set to the assertion ID as per the SAML specification recommendation. The ID is mandatory.